# System hangs while using chromedriver 2.20 for chrome browser automation

Tags: google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, automation, webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am using chromedriver 2.20 for chrome browser automation. But system hangs when the execution starts. Tried with chromedriver 2.19 also.

Driver initialization:

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", rootDir+ "/resources/drivers/chromedriver.exe");
driver = new ChromeDriver();
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
driver.manage().deleteAllCookies();
```

System Config:
Intel core i7 processor, 64bit OS, RAM: 16GB

Please suggest any solution.

Comment: What is version of your chrome browser?

Comment: Chrome browser version 46.0.24

Comment: You said you tried with versions "2.19 and 2.19". Was one of those supposed to be "2.18"?

Answer (score 0):

Not facing any issue with below sample code on Win 7, 64-bit. Please share chromedriver log

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","/path/to/chromedriver.exe"));
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(1, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
driver.manage().deleteAllCookies();
driver.get("http://www.google.com/");
System.out.println(driver.getTitle());
```